# UIScrollView fades out while dragging the last page

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm developing an iOS 7 app with latest SDK.

I have an `UIScrollView` with three `ImageView`s inside it. The `UIScrollView` has its `contentSize` set to `{960, 568}` (each `ImageView` has a {320, 958}` size).

I can drag over the three images perfectly, but I want to hide the `UIScrollView` when user drags from right to left on the last image.

To that, I have used `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 640)
        scrollView.hidden = YES;
}
```

But this code hide it immediately and I want to show the following effect:

- Continue dragging the image from right to left while the image fades out.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: apply UIView animate block enclosing scrollView.alpha=0, and at completion remoivefromsuperView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the fade effect proportional to the content offset, use this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 640)
    {
        scrollView.alpha = 1 / (scrollView.contentOffset.x - 639);
    }

    // then remove / hide the view completely at a particular offset
    // ....

}
```

and you can change the division to make the animation more/less smooth. This is smoother:

```
scrollView.alpha = 2 / (scrollView.contentOffset.x - 638);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
     self.scrollView.alpha = 0.0;
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     // remove the scrollView from your view
      if(finished) {
          [self.scrollView removeFromSuperview];
       }
 }];
```

Hopefully this will help

Comment: if you can accept my answer, so it helps others also

Comment: Your code, without any modification works great, but if I add: `[scrollView removeFromSuperview];` it disappears very fast.

Comment: Still happens. If I don't remove it from its superview it works perfectly. Why do I need to remove it from its superview?

Comment: you can leave it, that depends on your code. And then fade in by putting self.scrollView.alpha = 1